# write on csv file whith beatutiful soup

Tags: html, csv, hyperlink, beautifulsoup

after trying enough to get the desired, crash again with `.csv` files.

I need to write the links obtained in a `.csv` one below the other . but I this complicated enough.

you can help?

Thank you

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
import time

count = 1
while (count < 99):

      html_page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.gxxxxxar/BUxxxR/H=1;OR=5;ST=;LxxTA_ARTICxxxS_PAGENUMBER='+str(count)+';/Disxxxxxxa.aspx',timeout=30)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
      for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://www.grzzzzo.zzzcz.azzz/PROzzzCTO/PROD_ID")}):
                print link.get('href')
            print(count)
      count=count+1
      time.sleep(10)
print "good bye"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple, open a file and just write each href you find as you iterate adding a newline to put one per line.

Why you probably get errors right now is you are using the unmaintained and [deprecated *Beautifulsoup3*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html)  when you should be using [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import time
url = "http://www.gxxxxxar/BUxxxR/H=1;OR=5;ST=;LxxTA_ARTICxxxS_PAGENUMBER={};/Disxxxxxxa.aspx"
with open("links.txt"," w") as out:
    for i in range(1, 99):
          html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url.format(i), timeout=30)
          soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
          for link in soup.select("a[href^=http://www.grzzzzo.zzzcz.azzz/PROzzzCTO/PROD_ID]"):
                out.write(link["href"] + "\n")
          time.sleep(10)
print "good bye"
```

I replaced you regex logic with a [*css selector*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that uses the same logic, find all the hrefs starting with`http://www.grzzzzo.zzzcz.azzz/PROzzzCTO/PROD_ID]"`, also range will do what you are doing in your while.

Comment: you are a genious. Thank you